# How to get host information if having its IP address within same wifi in android?

Tags: android, ip, wifi, network-printers

I can have IP address of all hosts connected with same wifi network in my android application. Now i want details of that particular host from its IP address so that i can know whether it is printer or not ?
How can i do it ?
Can anybody help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, you could try the JMDNS library to check for all the service types. Most of the devices now-a-days broadcast a lot of info about themselves.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a complicated library that will find that for you, but the easiest way is to see if the host has port 515 open, which is the Line Printer Daemon port.

To do that, just attempt a connection on that port, and if it succeeds you can reasonably assume that it is a printer or a print server.